# How to read contents of a file line by line

Tags: c++, file-handling

hy...
    My program simply enters text line in a file.
Then it takes a line as input from user and checks it if it is present in the file.
if yes it shows "found" otherwise "not found".
Problem is that while reading file it just checks the last line in the file,and shows "not found" for the previous lines.Please guide me how can i read all the lines one by one and compare them with input string.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>
#include<conio.h>

using namespace std;

void main()
{
    int x=0,y=1;
    string f;
    while(x!=1){
        ofstream myfile("try.txt",ios::app);
        if(myfile.is_open())
            {
                cin>>f;
                myfile << f <<endl;
                myfile.close();
            }
        else
            {cout<<"file could not be opened";}
        cout<<"enter more?"<<endl;
        cin>>x;
    }

    string line;
    string a;
    cin>>a;
    ifstream yfile("try.txt");
    if(yfile.is_open())
        {
            while(getline (yfile,line))
                {
                    if(line==a)
                        {y=0;}
                    else
                        {y++;}
                }
            if(y==0)
                {cout<<"found"<<endl;}
            else
                {cout<<"match not found"<<endl;}
            yfile.close();
        }
    getch();

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to break out of your while loop when you make a match

```
while(getline (yfile,line))
{
  if(line==a)
  {
    y=0;
    break;  //<--- match found so exit loop
  }
  else
  {
    y++;
  }
}
```

otherwise when you encounter a mismatch you override any previous found matches (because `y` is incremented and you specifically check `y == 0` in order to print the match message). Thus if the last line does not match you dont detect it